# Yii2 - DetailView widget float left

Tags: css, widget, yii2

I'm trying to override the disposal of the `DetailView` widget by applying new css class but with no luck. I want all the records shown in the several instances of a `DetailView` widget to appear side by side. I create a class in `app\web\css` called `detail1-view` and apply it to the `detaiview.php` in vendor folder. The class has `float:left`, or `display:inline-block` in it, but none of the attributes work.

My Detailview is:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
      //'titulo',
      'noticia',
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que
        // carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
            'attribute'=>'fotodir',
            'value'=>$model->fotodir,
            'format' => ['image', ['width'=>'230','height'=>'200']],
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

and my `detailview.php` in folder `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/widgets/...` has in it the `detail1-view` class in the right place:

```
public $options = ['class' => 'detail1-view'];
```

My CSS:

```
.detail1-view {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%; 
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

The `DetailView` continues to display one in top of another and not side by side.

Anybody has a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I solved it by myself.**

The trick was to create another class with position:relative; and put the detailview widget inside it.

**Here's the code for the view:**

```
<div class="detail-disposal">
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options' => ['class' => 'detail1-view'],
    'attributes' => [
      //'titulo',
      'noticia',
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
        'attribute'=>'fotodir',
        'value'=>$model->fotodir,
        'format' => ['image',['width'=>'230','height'=>'200']],
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

**and the css style used in app/web/css:**

```
.detail-disposal{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

**DetailView CSS:**

```
.detail1-view {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    float:left;
    width: 300px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**Now the detailview widget appears side by side every time a model is called.**