# Yii2 Listview by column

Tags: yii2

may I help to view the records of a `Listview` side by side (columns), similar to extension [ecolumnlistview](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ecolumnlistview/) for Yii 1.x.

Obs .: I found no similar component

Comment: You should edit with some code to help you.

Comment: I follow this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771463/yii2-detailview-widget-float-left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771463/yii2-detailview-widget-float-left) Its work fine

Comment: Right  .. I was going to suggest, but you came before

Comment: I suggest you of post you solution like answer and after a few day you can mark it as accepted .. the answer could be useful to someone else

Comment: Try : https://packagist.org/packages/circulon/yii2-columnlistview

Comment: @Ororuk this work fine too, thanks

Comment: I follow this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771463/yii2-detailview-widget-float-left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771463/yii2-detailview-widget-float-left) Its work fine